# How to connect two servers tomcat, to a single project

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I read a tutorial on how to set up two servers tomcat:

http://kief.com/running-multiple-tomcat-instances-on-one-server.html

I use tomCat plugin in my Eclipce. As you can see, the path to a single server...
[image]

**Tell me, can I set up two servers using tomCat plugin?**

Comment: Seeing the properties tree, I'm afraid you'll have to choose either one.

Comment: try the servers view, maybe that will provide an option